# C++ Qt not taking the user input for simple code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string name;
cout << "Enter the name : "; //working fine
cin >> name;  //here is the problem,if i press my name and enter, the cursor is going 
              //to next line
cout << name; // its not displaying
return 0;
};
```

I have installed qt6 newly in my machine, i have written a simple c++ code take the
user input string (name) and displaying it.It was buliding successfully in qt6 app but if
we give the input and press enter , it is not taking the  user input.

Comment: Try outputting a newline character after `name` to flush `std::cout`.  Also, this has nothing to do with `Qt`.

Comment: do you mean you are using Qtbuilder ? Thats just an IDE, a fancy editor, with a button to invoke the compiler. Unless "its not displaying" means "the console window closes before the output is visible", the ide is not relevant for the question. The code is not using any qt